# How to connect to a Postgres database cluster ( running on digital Ocean) from a linux virtual machine (running on digital Ocean)?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `postgres` database cluster running on `digital ocean`, and another separate `virtual machine` also on the `digital ocean`. How can I connect to the database via `CLI` to the database I already have on the `digitalocean`?

This is what I have done so far.

- Installed `postgres` on vm

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib -y
```

- Modified `postgres.conf` file

```
# command
vi /etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf

# changes added  in the file
listen_addresses = "*"
```

- made changes inside `pg_hba.conf` file

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               password
```

- Restarted VM
   `sudo reboot`
- Tried connecting using this command (replaced constants with actual credentials):

```
psql --host=HOSTNAME --port=PORTNAME --username=USERNAME --dbname=DBNAME --password
```

- Then I get error:

> ```
> psql: error: connection to server at "<DBNAME>.db.ondigitalocean.com" 
> (IP ADDRESS), port (PORT NUMBER)failed: 
> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "USERNAME"
> connection to server at "<DBNAME>.db.ondigitalocean.com" 
> (IP ADDRESS), port (PORT NUMBER)failed: 
> FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for 
> host "(IP ADDRESSS)", user "(USERNAME)", database "DBNAME", no encryption
> ```

- If I access through `root`, I get the following message:

> ```
> Connection timed out
>         Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
> ```

Please help me how I can fix it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Timeout is usually a firewall issue. Is there a route set up to allow incoming connections and outgoing from the box ?